# Sharepoint List - Configure Layout , want to change the Title color based on selection of choice type column "Category" . Sharing the code below

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

In Sharepoint online list - Configure Layout, I want to change the Title color based on selection of choice type column "Category".

Sharing the current code below:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": " ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
    },
    "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "justify-content": "left",
        "font-size": "24px",
        "border-radius": "10px 10px 0 0",
        "padding": "8px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "justify-content": "space-between",
                "border-radius": "10px 10px 0 0",
                "padding": "8px",
                "font-size": "24px"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "Group",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                        "title": "Details"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "0px",
                        "height": "36px"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "=if([$Category] == 'ABC', 'ms-fontColor-BgMintGreen'"
            },
            "style": {
                "font-weight": "bold",
                "padding": "18px 13px",
                "overflow": "hidden"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=' Details - ' + [$Title]",
                    "style": {
                        "font-weight": "bold",
                        "padding": "18px 11px",
                        "overflow": "hidden"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "[$Category]",
                    "style": {
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "display": "flex",
                        "padding": "4px 14px",
                        "font-size": "10px"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of title text, you can use color attribute like:

```
"color": "=if([$Category] == 'ABC', 'green', if([$Category] == 'XYZ', 'red', 'black'))"
```

Here's the complete JSON:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": " ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
  },
  "style": {
    "display": "flex",
    "justify-content": "left",
    "font-size": "24px",
    "border-radius": "10px 10px 0 0",
    "padding": "8px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "justify-content": "space-between",
        "border-radius": "10px 10px 0 0",
        "padding": "8px",
        "font-size": "24px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "Group",
            "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
            "title": "Details"
          },
          "style": {
            "flex": "none",
            "padding": "0px",
            "padding-left": "0px",
            "height": "36px"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "=' Details - ' + [$Title]",
          "style": {
            "font-weight": "bold",
            "padding": "18px 11px",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "color": "=if([$Category] == 'ABC', 'green', if([$Category] == 'XYZ', 'red', 'black'))"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "[$Category]",
          "style": {
            "text-align": "center",
            "display": "flex",
            "padding": "4px 14px",
            "font-size": "10px"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, using the above suggested color attribute solved my code issue. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please **[Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)** and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.